# Set database value to NULL

Tags: sqlite, c++builder, firedac, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I have an SQLite double field that is used to display a date.  There is no default value for the field.  I need the field value to be NULL when there is no date entered because when the field is displayed as a date, it shows '12/30/1899'. For some reason, I cannot set the field to NULL.  I am using C++ Berlin 10.1.  Here is the code:

```
FDQuery1->First();
while (!FDQuery1->Eof) {
    if (!VarIsNull(FDQuery1->FieldByName("DateLeft")->Value))
        if (FDQuery1->FieldByName("DateLeft")->Value < 100) {
            FDQuery1->Edit();
            FDQuery1->FieldByName("DateLeft")->Value = NULL;
            FDQuery1->Post();
        }
    FDQuery1->Next();
}
```

"FDQuery1->FieldByName("DateLeft")->Value" is still 0 after running this code.

How can I set the value to NULL?

Comment: NULL in C++ is not the same thing as NULL in SQL.

Comment: What are the types of all these objects? I don't recognise `VarIsNull` for example, and it is highly unlikely that they can recognise the expression represented by the C macro `NULL` as standing in for the SQL keyword "NULL" (not least because it is indistinguishable from `0` in a numerical context...). What does the documentation say?

Comment: [This](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) is the SQLite C (and C++) interface I'd recognise.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that this question is *really* about FireDAC, which is the technology you're using in C++ to interface with a database. It doesn't really matter what that database is (SQLite or something else).

[The official documentation I found](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Displaying,_Converting,_and_Accessing_Field_Values) isn't much help, but we can already assume that writing the C macro `NULL` like this isn't going to do what you want. That's a utility for C code that, when converted to a number, is *zero*.

It is not possible for the FireDAC library to notice that you gave the expression `NULL` rather than `0`, because the expression `NULL` holds no type information that says that's what it is (at best, it'll be a `void*`, so you may get some weird string-like semantics out of it — this weirdness is why `nullptr` was added in C++11!).

So, `NULL` is not the right tool for the job. Yes, I know that SQL has a keyword called `NULL` that looks the same and does what you want in an SQL query, but we're not writing SQL. We're writing C++. So we can forget that.

I found some old [Delphi chatter](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/database/f56.shtml) that seems to discuss the same (or a similar) interface and suggests using the `Clear()` method on a field to erase its value, implicitly making it "null".

Give that a go.

So, something like:

```
FDQuery1->FieldByName("DateLeft")->Clear();
```